# Python, how to implement something like .gitignore behavior

Tags: python, pattern-matching, gitignore, glob, fnmatch

I need to list all files in the current directory (.) (including all sub directories), and exclude some files as how .gitignore works (http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

With fnmatch (https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) I will be able to "filter" files using a pattern

```
ignore_files = ['*.jpg', 'foo/', 'bar/hello*']
matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
  for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*'):
      matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

how can I "filter" and get all files which doesn't match with one or more element of my "ignore_files"?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't need all the specification, only to exclude some files using patterns from a list of files.

Comment: Is there a reason you tagged this regex? Those are clearly glob-style patterns in your code, not regular expressions. While you _can_ convert them to regexps (with `fnmatch.translate`), did you have any reason to believe you might need to? If so, that reason should be in your question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're on the right track: If you want to use `fnmatch`-style patterns, you should use [`fnmatch.filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter) with them.

But there are three problems that make this not quite trivial.

First, you want to apply multiple filters. How do you do that? Call `filter` multiple times:

```
for ignore in ignore_files:
    filenames = fnmatch.filter(filenames, ignore)
```

Second, you actually want to do the *reverse* of `filter`: return the subset of names that *don't* match. As the documentation explains:

> It is the same as `[n for n in names if fnmatch(n, pattern)]`, but implemented more efficiently.

So, to do the opposite, you just throw in a `not`:

```
for ignore in ignore_files:
    filenames = [n for n in filenames if not fnmatch(n, ignore)]
```

Finally, you're attempting to filter on partial pathnames, not just filenames, but you're not doing the `join` until after the filtering. So switch the order:

```
filenames = [os.path.join(root, filename) for filename in filenames]
for ignore in ignore_files:
    filenames = [n for n in filenames if not fnmatch(n, ignore)]
matches.extend(filenames)
```

---

There are few ways you could improve this.

You may want to use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension (parentheses instead of square brackets), so if you have huge lists of filenames you're using a lazy pipeline instead of wasting time and space repeatedly building huge lists.

Also, it may or may not be easier to understand if you invert the order of the loops, like this:

```
filenames = (n for n in filenames 
             if not any(fnmatch(n, ignore) for ignore in ignore_files))
```

Finally, if you're worried about performance, you can use `fnmatch.translate` on each expression to turn them into equivalent regexps, then merge them into one big regexp and compile it, and use that instead of a loop around `fnmatch`. This can get tricky if your patterns are allowed to be more complicated than just `*.jpg`, and I wouldn't recommend it unless you really do identify a performance bottleneck here. But if you need to do it, I've seen at least one question on SO where someone put a lot of effort into hammering out all the edge cases, so search instead of trying to write it yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is my code now (end-to-end):

ignore_files = ['foo', '*/foo']

matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
  for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*'):
      filename = os.path.join(root, filename)[2:]
      matches.append(filename)

for ignore in ignore_files:
    matches_ = [n for n in matches if not fnmatch.filter([n], ignore)]

can be better?
thanks

Comment: @fj123x: You really can't post code in comments, because they eat all the formatting. Either post a new question, edit it into your existing question, or stick it somewhere like http://pastebin.com and post a link here.

Comment: @fj123x: But one quick comment: There's no reason to ever `fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*')`. All filenames match `*`, so that just returns a copy of `filenames`.

Comment: This doesn't really handle [`.gitignore` rules](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) like `**/a/b`, `a/b/**` and `a/**/b` nor would it seem to handle a simple `foo`. For example `foo` in .gitignore will match `foo` and `a/foo` but fnmatch will fail on `a/foo`

Comment: [Yea, doesn't seem to work at all](https://repl.it/x3D/1) though maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

```
import os

from git import Repo


def list_files_in_directory(directory_path):
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(directory_path, ".git")):
        repo = Repo(directory_path)
        return repo.git.ls_files().splitlines()
    else:
        file_list = []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory_path):
            for file in files:
                file_list.append(
                    os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file), directory_path)
                )
        return file_list
```

Answer (score -1):

```
matches.extend([fn for fn if not filename in ignore_files])
```

Should do the trick for simple filenames, for ignore patterns something like:

```
def reject(filename, filter):
    """ Takes a filename and a filter to reject files that match."""
    if len(filter)==0:
         return False
    else:
         return fnmatch.fnmach(filename, filter[0]) or reject(filename, filter[1:])

matches.extend([os.path.join(root, fn) for fn in filenames if not reject(fn, ignore_files)])
```

The above will while building a list from the filenames in the os.walk check that none of the filters provide a match - the filters are checked until either there are none left or the first match is found so it should be quite quick.

You could also try something like:

```
filenames = set(filenames)  # convert to a set
for filter in ignore_files:
   filenames = filenames - set(fnmatch.filter(filenames, filter)) # remove the matches
matches.extend([os.path.join(root, fn) for fn in filenames])  # Add to matches
```

Comment: Only if `ignore_files` is a list of simple file names, `.gitignore` and `fnmatch` permit glob patterns and it's extremely useful. There's even one in OP's example (`*.jpg`).

Comment: Misled be the naming - ignore_files rather than ignore_patterns

Comment: Note that some of the patterns match paths, not just filenames.

Comment: can you explain the usage of matches.extend([fn for fn if not reject(filename, ignore_files)])? you are not using the "in" in the sentence, and what filename would be? Thanks

Comment: @fj123x: The listcomp is missing `in filenames` between the `for fn` and the `if not`. You'll need to add it to make this work. But as delnan pointed out, this won't work for you anyway.