# Git: List files that should be ignored, but are not

Tags: git, gitignore

#### Note

This is not about fixing like `git rm -r --cached . && git add .` I actually want to be able to list the files only.

#### Why

Sometimes when I edit my `.gitignore` and forget the above command I end up with files that are still in the repository, but should have been ignored.

#### What

What I want to accomplish is to write a shell script, that is able to list all files on my filesystem that *should* have been ignored, but are still present.

#### Outcome

In the end, I want to implement it to a continuous integration server, which will check if the rules from `.gitignore` match the files that are inside the repository.

Is there any way to parse the `.gitignore` by hand?

Comment: If python is acceptable (or at least usable as inspiration) then [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25229592/258523) might be of some help.

Answer (score 14):

```
git ls-files --cached --ignored --exclude-standard
```

Comment: Completely forgot about ls-files. This is the best all `git` solution to this question.

Comment: I have `git config --global alias.ls ls-files --exclude-standard` :-)

Comment: Nice, I'll definitely be adding an alias for this. Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: For this, my output is empty. I know I have a lot of local files which are being ignored and are not in the repository. But the command returns with no results

Comment: The `--cached` option says to only list indexed aka cached aka staged aka added aka tracked paths.  If this returns no results, no tracked paths match an ignore pattern.

Comment: would love a one liner that then deletes these files.

Answer (score -1):

You should look at the `git check-ignore --help` You can use it to check if a path should be included or excluded. From my understanding, to do what you want you should use the `--no-index` option.

That's at least the `git` side of the process.

The shell side of the process would involve more. You have many options there. You could use find to list all files and pipe them git check-ignore and based on the output of that create a list of files that should have been excluded.

That's my 2¢ anyway.

Here's an SO question that covers something similar [Git command to show which specific files are ignored by .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466764/show-ignored-files-in-git)